# AngularJS - Double curly brackets causing Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to print out the $index of ng-repeat, but it gives me:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [markers{{ $index }}] starting at [{{ $index }}].
```

This is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places">
         <leaflet id="map{{ $index }}" defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers{{ $index }}"></leaflet>
</div>
```

But changing to this works:

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places">
     <leaflet id="map{{ $index }}" defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers0"></leaflet>
```

This is very strange...why does that happen?

Comment: In your directive, is markers binding a '=' type?

Comment: @arg20 I think the markers attribute has a string type if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: can you show us the code for your directive scope?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the directive of `leaflet` it does have `=` form markers, [**See this code**](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js#L18)

`=` means you enabaled to way binding inside your isolated, for that you must have provide scope variable reference in that attribute.

Where `markers0` does work because you provided the scope reference,

But when you provide `{{}}` interpolation in that attribute will get failed as you are doing like `markers="markers{{ $index }}"`

For handle this issue elegantly i would prefer you to create one array of `markers` that will have multiple values you that the data will become like this

```
$scope.markers = [{...},{...},{...},...]
```

instead of

```
$scope.marker0 = {}, $scope.marker1 = {}, $scope.marker2 = {}, ....
```

So that you could easily point to that from using its `$index`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="place in places">
    <leaflet id="map{{ $index }}" defaults="defaults" center="center" 
     markers="markers[$index]"></leaflet>
</div>
```

Comment: I typically avoid relying on $index since things get weird when you start filtering or ordering elements with filters, but this covers the basic problem.

Comment: @shaunhusain you are correct..rather he can some `id` property inside each `place` that would somehow refer to markers.

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks, but when using `markers="markers[$index]"` it renders out exactly as `markers="markers[$index]"`... the $index was not replaced...

Comment: @PankajParkar I mean I have tried but the $index was not replaced by any value...

Comment: make sure it should be inside ng-repeat, then only $index will get evaluated.could you update a question..wHat you have tried till now..

Comment: @PankajParkar It is definitely inside ng-repeat... my code now is exactly the same as the markup in your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue but with a different directive.
One work around I did was actually placing a single quote before and after the curly brackets

```
 <div ng-repeat="place in places">
     <leaflet id="map{{ $index }}" defaults="defaults" center="center" markers="markers'{{ $index }}'"></leaflet>
 </div>
```